# Certificate error when using docker buildx

Tags: docker, build

I am having a very weird issue when building an armv7 docker image using docker [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/), but not when building it natively on armv7 hardware.

Here is a very simple docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG ARCH

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl wget

# Install Go
ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.15.8
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    url="https://golang.org/dl/go${GOLANG_VERSION}.linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz"; \
    wget -O go.tgz "$url"; \
    tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz; \
    rm go.tgz; \
    export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"; \
    go version
```

I can build the image for arm64 both on macos as well on a raspberrypi just fine. No such luck when building it for armv7 tho.

I am building the image on macos using buildx as follows:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t test:armv7 --build-arg ARCH=armv6l .
```

This fails with a certificate error when connecting to golang.org:

```
#7 0.378 Resolving golang.org (golang.org)... 142.250.185.113, 2a00:1450:4001:80f::2011
#7 0.448 Connecting to golang.org (golang.org)|142.250.185.113|:443... connected.
#7 0.682 ERROR: cannot verify golang.org's certificate, issued by 'CN=GTS CA 1O1,O=Google Trust Services,C=US':
#7 0.682   Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
#7 0.688 To connect to golang.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

However if I build the exact same image natively on armv7 (raspberry pi 2b) it works just fine:

```
docker build -t test:armv7 --build-arg ARCH=armv6l .
```

Needless to say I am very confused why one works and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

add to wget command to do not check a ssl certificate `-k` argument

for you

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG ARCH

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl wget

# Install Go
ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.15.8
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    url="https://golang.org/dl/go${GOLANG_VERSION}.linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz"; \
    wget -k -O go.tgz "$url"; \
    tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz; \
    rm go.tgz; \
    export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"; \
    go version
```

best way it will be install the ca-cerificates pacage. do this in `apt-get install -y curl wget ca-certificates`

Comment: Well this would be the workaround yeah, but I am interested in the root cause.

Comment: ok, you have to download root CA certificates, you can do installing ca-certificates, just add to apt-get install -y curl wget the package ca-certifiactes

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the post, but I already tried that and it had no effect. That's why I am so confused.

Comment: Hmm, check your date time

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The date seems to be correct, adding `RUN date` prints `Sat Feb  6 20:37:03 UTC 2021`.

Comment: I know there has some time passed meanwhile, but did you reboot the buildx container after installing the certificates?